# How to make "ping" display a less verbose output

Tags: windows, batch

How is it possible for "ping" in windows to display less information e.g. a less verbose output.

E.g. just the "Reply from" part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any option to do that, at least in Windows XP. But you can do this:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 | find "TTL"
```

This filters the final stats.

Comment: @dario_ramos Thanks, but what if the locale was not english?

Comment: ping 127.0.0.1 | find "TTL" would be more ideal

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the lines which have reply:

```
ping servername | find "Reply"
```

Comment: @Raoul ping 127.0.0.1 | find "TTL" (taking into account different locales

Comment: @Peter sure, I didn't see a local independent requirement in your post